# Unable to return dropdown with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tired to try where is my fault .. please show me where is the mistake .. 
thank you

Controller

```
public function bulidSub()
{
    $id_kategori = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['sub_kategori']= $this->db->get_where('sub_kategori', array('id_kategori' => $id_kategori));
    $output = null;
    foreach ($data['sub_kategori']->result() as $row)
    {
        //here we build a dropdown item line for each query result
        $output .= "<option value='".$row->id_sub_kategori."'>".$row->nama_sub_kategori."</option>";
    }
    echo  $output;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#kategori").change(function(){
               var id_kategori = $("select#kategori option:selected").attr('value');

                 /*dropdown post */
                $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>/admin/buildSub/"+id_kategori,    
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){           
                    $("#sub_kategori").html(data);
                }
                });//
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: is ajax request is going correctly? check your console

Answer (score 1):

Test the output in browser by calling it directly instead of AJAX.

Function in PHP is bulidSub and you calling buildSub from AJAX. Also I'd use

```
buildSub($id_kategori = null) instead of $this->uri->segment(3)
```

Comment: I've replaced it but still can not.
I show above the code view

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax..

```
$data['sub_kategori']->result()
```

Change it to

```
$data['sub_kategori']->result
```